# Highcharts: Renderer positioning issue on different screen size breakpoints

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am using the Highcharts` renderer to render custom icons on the chart (in my case trophy icons above columns, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLrah/544/)).

On different layout breakpoints (on xAxis label rotation changes), the positioning of the trophy gets corrupted (see the attached images):

[Correct positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OjKg.png)

[Wrong positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZkXB.png)

The relevant code for the icon positioning is:

```
this.renderer.image('http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-6fc6f09b8c986ade7286aa71ba43c71e-trophy.png',
                     point.plotX - (imgWidth/5), 
                     point.plotY + imgHeight, 
                     imgWidth, 
                     imgHeight)
.attr({zIndex: 3})
.add()
```

Is this a bug or do I have to add some additional dynamic padding?

Thanks,

Philipp

Comment: Have you thought about creating a separate series to contain your trophies, and place them like highcharts symbol example: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/ ? That would make them dynamic and scale with the rest of the chart. The other option is to re-render your trophies after scale has changed (which is also doable).

Comment: I do not see the marker option on column chart types. Am I missing something?

Comment: By creating a seperate series, I meant a scatter series, that only has values where there are trophies.

Comment: I have added your idea (see http://jsfiddle.net/bLrah/558/). You talked about dynamic scale, how is this achieved now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include `chart.plotTop` in the calculations. Properties `plotX` and `plotY` from points are in relation to `plotArea` and the `chart.renderer` method includes the entire chart.

```
this.renderer.image(
    url, 
    point.plotX - (imgWidth / 5), 
    point.plotY + this.plotTop - imgHeight, 
    imgWidth, 
    imgHeight
).attr({
    zIndex: 3
}).add();
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/svp7rnkg/

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have also added the plotTop to the animation (see http://jsfiddle.net/svp7rnkg/2/). Now, it works. Is it also possible to autoscale the image according to the chart dimensions?

Comment: Hi Philipp Staudt, No, but you can make the image size dependent on chart size: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/thqd4m82/